# Add Image to Tabs using Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-tabs

I have 3 different Tabs, where each one has text. Now I want to find out how to Add drawable images on top of the text of the tab. I know that this was possible using tabhosts but that has been deprecated. My class is the following :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Sample code:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon).setTabListener(this));
```

**But please consider:**
 Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider using other common navigation patterns instead. (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

---

**Edit:**
For your Code you could do something like this:

Create the icons as you do for the titles:

```
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };
//make sure this has the same length as tabs-array!
private int[] icons = {R.drawable.tab_rated, R.drawable.tab_games, R.drawable.tab_movies}
```

And add them in a loop:

```
// Adding Tabs
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
   actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setIcon(icons[i]).setTabListener(this));
}
```

Comment: Hello, the code you provided me with works. The only problem is that it will assign the same drawable icon to all tabs. I would like to know how to add a different drawable to each tab element.

Comment: Well then change the "R.drawable.tab_icon" to whatever drawable you like. I will update my answer in a moment...